# Disk of solid wood debris on a 0.8 mm end-mill

Tags: machining, cnc

The machine makes a cutout in a 6 mm-thick piece of hard maple using a 0.8 mm end-mill.
The end-mill accumulates a quite solid disk of wood debris. It has the consistency of soap and looks like a fine dust glued together with wood resin. The disk is especially solid at its bottom, might be because the machined material incrementally pushes it.

The spindle runs at its maximum of 12000 rpm. Feed rate is 45 mm/min, depth step 0.7 mm.

Can the dirt be a source of problems or is it harmless? If it is the former, how can I prevent the dirt from accumulating? The machine has a dust collector which otherwise works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Likely the speed and pressure is causing the chips to combine much like pellets are made.

Reduce the speed and stop for cleaning cycles.